# Красивое решение - перегрузка метода

Tags: php, методы

Есть класс **profile**, в нем метод получения комментариев текущего пользователя:

```
private function getComments(){
$comments  = $this->comments_model->GetCommentsLov(array('limit' => $this->climit, 'IdToUser' => $this->idUser));

$this->data['comments']    = $this->commentsuser->SetCommentsFields(null, 5, $comments,

$this->idUser);
$this->data['viewSection'] = 'comments/item';
}
```

Каждый пользователь имеет свой тип профиля *private $typeProfile;*
В зависимости от которого, нужно подгружать комментарии, относящиеся к этом у профилю. Т-е в методе **getComments()** обращаться к другому методы модели **$this->comments_model;**

Как это можно красиво сделать?

Comment: Приватные методы нельзя перегружать

Comment: Пусть это будет публичный - не суть...

Comment: getComments($GetCommentsLov){.... ->$GetCommentsLov(...

Comment: Это что за запись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Abcd
{
    private $typeProfile;
    public function getProfileType()
    {
        return $this->typeProfile;
    }
}
```

...

```
class Efgh extends Abcd
{
    public function getComments()
    {
        $profileType = $this->getProfileType();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: А если в пределах одного класса?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, какую тогда вообще разницу имеет приватность $typeProfile?